# Monitoring Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, ios8

Is there a method to receive all notifications posted to the notification center, I note that this is exactly what the Microsoft Band iOS app is capable of doing, I would be interested in implementing something similar for my app (simply counts per app rather than any kind of detail).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apple Notification Center Service to do this. Here is a link to the docs which have a tendency to break, but may help you find the info you need. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html